# How, specifically, does the game engines friction work?

Tags: game-engine, physics, collision

I have a `dynamic` physics-typed object. Its material has an option for the amount of friction:

[image]

Here is what it tells us:

[image]

Well, refer to the first picture. We see, under `Force Field` an option for distance. Here is what it tells us:

[image]

I have a few questions on how this works:

#### How is the distance created?

Is it a *box* around the object? *Convex hull*? A distance from *any* point on the object? Using `Game` > `Show Physics Visualization`, where exactly is this area?

#### Why does friction still occur when there is zero distance of the physics area

The `Friction` option tells us that the changes occur "when inside the physics distance area." Why is velocity still truncated with distance of the physics area?

#### What formula does the friction use?

- What about environmental friction (i.e. friction *from other sources*)?
- Does it use the common method introduced back in Quake? (Sorry about the example not being in python; although, it is very understandable.)
  [image]
- What is the *exact* formula/method of determining exactly how much velocity to truncate?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Friction` belongs to the surface. When the object touches the surface the combined frictions result in a sliding force (both objects have materials).

`Distance` and `Force` belongs to `force field`. The force field is defined above the faces with that material. 'Above' means

- +Z (global) when `Align to Normal` is unset
- +Z (local) when `Align to Normal` is set

I can't tell about the formulas, nor if friction belongs to force field too.